# How to write a query in Hasura Data Api to give output based on input by user

Tags: postgresql, hasura

How to write the postgres sql body in Hasura data api to get some result by taking input from user.
 The sql query is like"Select moviedetails from table name where movie_name='name enterd by user'.I want to know the structure to accept data from user

```
url = "https://data.incipiently69.hasura-app.io/v1/query"
```

## This is the json payload for the query

requestPayload = {
    "type": "select",
    "args": {
        "table": "collect",
        "columns": [
            "overview"
        ]
    }
}

## Setting headers

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

## Make the query and store response in resp

resp = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(requestPayload), headers=headers)

## resp.content contains the json response.

print(resp.content)

Comment: This isn't an appropriate site for your question. I recommend that you seek a site with the word "forum" in the name.

Comment: Sure I would take care of this in future

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to substitute data retrieved from the user input in the where clause of the API query.

```
user_input = req.body.user_input

requestPayload = {
  "type": "select",
  "args": {
    "table": "collect",
    "columns": ["overview", "movie_name"],
    "where": {
        "movie_name": user_input
    }
  }
}
```